# I need to make a program in C# which counts the digits in a variable, but I can't convert that variable to string

Tags: c#, numbers

This is what I have so far:

```
int num = 12345;

int length = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(num)+1);

Console.WriteLine(length);    
Console.ReadKey();
```

The output should be 5.
This is obviously giving me errors, but I really don't know another way of how to do it since the instructions are so clear to **not use**  `ToString`.

Any help or guidance would be appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: `while ( ( num /= 10 ) != 0 ) counter++` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this:  The really lazy easy way, and a slightly less lazy but simpler-to-understand way.

Here's the easy way.  It's almost what you did, but with a few tweaks to handle the zero corner-case, and the requisite cast:

```
int length = number > 0 ? (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(number)) + 1 : 1;
```

The slightly less lazy solution is repeated division by ten; to know how many digits there are, you just keep dividing by ten until you run out of them:

```
int length = 0;
while (number > 0) {
    length++;
    number /= 10;
}
if (length < 1) length = 1;
```

The last "less than one" check is because you obviously can't have a number with no digits at all in it.

As one of the commenters noted, this only works for nonnegative integers.  (But then the "length" of a negative integer is an interesting meta-question in and of itself; should you include the sign as part of the length, or is it merely the number of digits?)  If you want it to work for negative values (or fractions), you'll have to convert them to positive values first, and then potentially add one more position for the sign, depending on what you're trying to compute.

Anyway, there ya go.  Nice and easy.

Comment: My bad:  Wrote it out too fast.  It's fixed now, and tested.

Answer (score 2):

The length is *1+⌊log<sub>10</sub>max(1,|x|)*⌋. So you can implement it like:

```
int length = 1+Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Max(1,Math.Abs(num))));
```

Examples in the `csharp` console:

```
csharp> for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      >     Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",i,1+Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Max(1,Math.Abs(i)))));   
      > }
0: 1
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1
4: 1
5: 1
6: 1
7: 1
8: 1
9: 1
10: 2
11: 2
12: 2
13: 2
14: 2
csharp> for(int i = 0; i > -15; i--) {                                               
      >     Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",i,1+Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Max(1,Math.Abs(i)))));
      > }
0: 1
-1: 1
-2: 1
-3: 1
-4: 1
-5: 1
-6: 1
-7: 1
-8: 1
-9: 1
-10: 2
-11: 2
-12: 2
-13: 2
-14: 2
```

Comment: You should make your example show the results of negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the number by 10 (i.e. shift the decimal separator) until all the digits are on the right side of the decimal separator:

```
public static int GetNumDigitsWithoutToString(int forInput)
{
    if (forInput == 0) return 1; // guard clause to prevent divide by zero error.
    int numDigits = 0;
    var x = (decimal) forInput;

    while (x >= 1)
    {
        numDigits++;
        x = x / 10;
    }

    return numDigits;
}
```

Comment: What if `num` is 1 or 0 or negative?

Answer (score 0):

IMO the easiest one to understand would be :

```
int num = 12345;
int counter = 1; // start counter with one because you'll automatically "remove" one sign
while ( ( num /= 10 ) != 0 ) counter++;

//Console.WriteLine(counter) >> 5;
```

This will work with negatives as well.

[online example](http://rextester.com/DGW39260)